# Query array elements instead of documents

Tags: mongodb

Can I query elements of arrays which are inside documents instead of querying whole documents? I. e. I want to receive array elements, not documents.
E. g., I have this:

```
{
  blog: 'blog1',
  comments:
  [{user: 'Alice', text: 'bla-bla-bla'}, {user: 'Sarah', text: 'bla-bla-bla'}, ...]
},
{
  blog: 'blog2',
  comments:
  [{user: 'John', text: 'bla-bla-bla'}, {user: 'Alice', text: 'bla-bla-bla'}, ...]
}
```

How can I get a list of comments written by Alice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this yet. See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828

Comment: It seems to be the most important feature necessary for real apps development!

Comment: @Andrey Not really. If you find yourself needing this then you're actually running into the results of questionable schema design. Either the comments array is small in which case it much more efficient to just return the entire thing and filter inside your app or it's large in which case it shouldn't be an embedded structure.

Comment: @Remon van Vliet Maybe, you're right. I was just looking for possibility to take advantage of embedding for performance-gains in comparison to RDBMS. Because splitting blogs and comments is actually what anybody would've done with RDBMS.

Comment: @Andrey Certainly, sometimes you find yourself normalizing data just as you would in RDBMS. Don't see that as a flaw as there is some overlap between RDBMS storage and NoSQL. Note that embedding isn't the big defining feature of MongoDB. Use it if it helps, don't if it doesn't. Even with collections split there are plenty of advantages and disadvantages compared to an RDBMS. Up to you to decide which way heavier and pick your tool accordingly.

Comment: It is a pretty nice convenience feature, regardless of performance. The aggregation framework is coming soon (less than a few months), if you want to keep this structure and be able to query for a list of "just Alice's comments" across all blogs shortly--rather than pulling it all down to the application to pull them out, which is probably the easiest way to do it now. (I don't recommend map/reduce for this sort of thing)

Comment: I guess I'll have to remember to update my answer when it comes out. :)